# read function getting extra letter c++

Tags: c++

```
int main() {
  int len;
  int file_len;
  cout<<"Enter the size of dynamic array you want: ";
  cin>>len;

  ifstream in("test.txt");

  char *ch = new char[len];
  in.read(ch, len);
  in.seekg(0, ios::end);
  file_len = in.tellg();
  in.close();


  if(file_len>len)
  {
    int times= file_len/len;

    ifstream in("test.txt");
    for(int i=0; i<times; i++)
    {

            char *n_ch = new char[len+1];
            in.seekg(0, ios::cur);
            in.read(n_ch, len);
            n_ch[len]= '\0';
            cout<<n_ch<<endl;
            delete n_ch;

    }
    in.close();

  } else {

    cout<<ch<<endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

What I am trying to do is to get the nth to (n+len)th letters and put them into an array, and then print them.
The content of test.txt is:

```
abcdefg
hijklmnop
qrstuv
wxyz
```

And the result I get is:

[image]

I get extra r at the end. I guess this is because the number of letters left at the end is less than len, which is 10.
Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: I think you want to check if the read succeeded like in this example: [http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/)

Comment: I'm trying to read the text into an array and pass it to a function, but I 'm geting an extra letter at the end of the text. How can I get rid of the extra letter?

Comment: `is.gcount()` in the example looks like it can help you determine how many characters were actually read.

Answer (score 1):

There's two potential problems I see:

```
n_ch[len]= '\0';
```

This assumes you will always read exactly `len` bytes. If you read fewer, there is going to be some junk between the nul terminating character and the data that was successfully read.

The other is in the case where the `if` condition fails; you never add a nul terminating character to the array pointed to by `ch` (like you do with `n_ch`) and so writing this as a string to standard output can cause an out-of-bounds read.

---

The preferred way to handle strings in C++ is with `std::string`, not arrays.  If you switch to using strings, a lot of the issues you are having here will simply go away -- and you won't have to worry about freeing your own memory, either.  You have two problems with memory management in just this simple example that would be automatically handled with `std::string`:

- You leak the allocation in `ch`.
- You call `delete n_ch;` when it points to an array allocation. You must do `delete[] n_ch;` instead.